# How can I guarantee that a user’s Facebook account has been successfully logged off from my own app? (ios)

Tags: ios

I’m currently encountering a bug in my app where my Facebook would remain logged in as the default account on my app, even though I’ve logged off the account within my app.

Answer (score 0):

set CurrentAccessToken to nil. This should work.

```
[FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil]
```

Comment: Thank you !I did, but It doesn't work. This my code.
   FBSDKLoginManager *fblogin = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
   [fblogin logOut];
logOut will call [FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil] and [FBSDKProfile setCurrentProfile:nil]

Answer (score 0):

facebook sdk, you can check

if(FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil) { //logged in } else { //not logged in }

Comment: Thx! I will check.